# undefined method `paths' for #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0xac73454> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, bundle

I am getting this error when I run bundle exec cucumber.  Is this a rails version error?  How can I check if the rails being used has this method defined in the Rails::Application::RoutesReloader class to see if I need to upgrade/downgrade?  If not, anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:

Stack Trace:

```
undefined method `paths' for #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0xac73454> (NoMethodError)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:517:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails/application.rb:15:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/hw3_rottenpotatoes/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:7:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/hw3_rottenpotatoes/features/support/env.rb:7:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/hw3_rottenpotatoes/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

I believe it is an error with rails because when I try to run rails server, it gives me the same error.  Something must have happened to the installation because that command ran before without a problem

Comment: It looks like your trying to call the method paths at some point in your test code (where there isn't a method called paths). The error message details probably gives you a line number you can look up and find where in your code that is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  From what I can see, it is trying to call the paths method of the Rails::Application::RoutesReloader class, which is internal to rails, and should have this method defined from what I can see in the API.

Comment: Could you edit the question, and include the error stack trace? It would make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, just added the stack trace.

Comment: Ok it is now running cucumber after running bundle update. I guess this updated my current gems to the newest ones, but I'm still a bit confused as to why exactly it worked. I had both railties 3.2.7 and 3.1.0 installed, tried changing the gemfile.lock to use the newest one (had tried this b4 unsuccesfully but w/out bundle update) and ran bundle update, but it just reverted the entry back to 3.1.0 and then "magically" worked.